# Something faster than urllib2.open()?

Tags: python

I'm building a thing that gathers data from a site. Sometimes it has to go through >10,000 pages, and opening each one with urllib2.urlopen() takes time. I'm not very hopeful about this, but does anyone know of a faster way to get html from a site?

my code is this :

```
import urllib, json, time
import requests
##########################
start_time = time.time()
##########################

query = "hill"
queryEncode = urllib.quote(query)
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={{MY API KEY}}&cx={{cxKey}}:omuauf_lfve&fields=queries(request(totalResults))&q='+queryEncode
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(str(response.read()))    

##########################
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print " url to json time : " + str(elapsed_time)
##########################
```

And the output is

```
 url to json time : 4.46600008011
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

Comment: How do you know it's `urllib2.urlopen` problem, not the site's?

Comment: As @DyZ say, it's pretty unlikely that `urllib2` is the problem here. Often you can speed things up by reading multiple requests in parallel (see one of the first examples in the docs for `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`), but that may not help, and may be considered "unfriendly" by the server. Sometimes you can speed things up by passing appropriate headers (if you want just the head or just the first 1K of the body, or want compressed data, or are OK with somewhat stale data from a cache, etc.).

Comment: Retrieving data from network takes time depending on numerous reasons. You can consider using multiple threads or other solutions fetching data asynchronously.